# sed whole word search and replace

Tags: shell, sed

How do I search and replace whole words using sed?

Doing

```
sed -i 's/[oldtext]/[newtext]/g' <file>
```

will also replace partial matches of `[oldtext]` which I don't want it to do.

Answer (score 207, accepted):

\b in regular expressions match word boundaries (i.e. the location between the first word character and non-word character):

```
$ echo "bar embarassment" | sed "s/\bbar\b/no bar/g"
no bar embarassment
```

Comment: [not posix](http://sed.js.org/?gist=0d0377fffd0f8b21886ff288bc260423)
| 
[GNU sed](http://sed.js.org/?gist=3c69aaff8facf8040a7c9556e80f0868) OK

Comment: @OlegMazko I also came looking for the posix acceptable method to use in vim and what worked for me was s/\<7//g.  I was trying to remove a 7 at the start of a word in my code.  This link, specifically, J-P's solution, led me to the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864467/whats-the-difference-between-vim-regex-and-normal-regex (couldn't get markdown to embed it like yours for some reason).

Comment: Thank you I was going mad trying to do a replacement on the word "and" so `\band\b` saved the day :)

Comment: Would be using `[[:space:]]word[[:space:]]` be considered acceptable @jimh

Comment: Didn't work for me. Maybe a different build of sed? Was default on CentOS 7

Comment: Didn't work for me either, but, silly me, it's because I forgot to escape the backslash, so bash swallowed it! It may be worth making that explicit in your answer.

Answer (score 164):

On Mac OS X, *neither* of these regex syntaxes work inside **sed** for matching whole words

- `\bmyWord\b`
- `\<myWord\>`

Hear me now and believe me later, *this* ugly syntax is what you need to use:

- `/[[:<:]]myWord[[:>:]]/`

So, for example, to replace *mint* with *minty* for whole words only:

- `sed "s/[[:<:]]mint[[:>:]]/minty/g"`

Source: [re_format man page](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man7/re_format.7.html)

Comment: Just install GNU `sed` (and every other GNU tool) via MacPorts or Homebrew and make sure it comes first in your `PATH`. It's possible to make a Mac fairly usable.

Comment: @JimStewart great way to break a bunch of tools that assume ‘when on OS X, do as the OS Xers.’ That said, I can definitely suggest `brew install coreutils`, which prefixes all of the gnu tools.

Comment: `brew install gnu-sed` to use `gsed`

Comment: brew coreutils is awesome.  are there any other brew packages which install a whole bunch of gnu versions of commands or do I need to install the rest individually?

Comment: answered my own question. there's a list of packages @ http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69223/how-to-replace-mac-os-x-utilities-with-gnu-core-utilities

Comment: Using perl is always a better solution: `perl -pe 's|\bone\b|two|g'`. Works stably while sed fails here and there.

Answer (score 21):

Use `\b` for word boundaries:

```
sed -i 's/\boldtext\b/newtext/g' <file>
```

Answer (score 9):

In one of my machine, delimiting the word with "`\b`" (without the quotes) did not work. The solution was to use "`\<`" for starting delimiter and "`\>`" for ending delimiter.

To explain with [Joakim Lundberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/51647/joakim-lundborg)'s example:

```
$ echo "bar embarassment" | sed "s/\<bar\>/no bar/g"
no bar embarassment
```

Answer (score 1):

For a posix compliant alternative, consider replacing word boundary matches (`\b`) by an expanded equivalent (`[^a-zA-Z0-9]`), also taking into account occurrences at start of line (`^`) and end of line (`$`).

However, this quickly becomes impractical if you want to support repeated occurrences of the word to replace (e.g. `oldtext oldtext`). `sed --posix` doesn't recognize expressions such as `\(^\|[^a-zA-Z0-9]\)`, and you can't make use of lookarounds.

It seems we have to explictly match all possible cases. Here's a solution to replace `mint` with `minty`:

```sh
echo 'mint 0mint mint mint0 mint__mint mint__ mint_ -mint mint mint mint_ mint -mint- mint mint mintmint mint' \
  | sed --posix '   
s/^mint$/minty/g;
s/^mint\([^a-zA-Z0-9]\)/minty\1/g;
s/\([^a-zA-Z0-9]\)mint$/\1minty/g;
s/\([^a-zA-Z0-9]\)mint\([^a-zA-Z0-9]\)mint\([^a-zA-Z0-9]\)mint\([^a-zA-Z0-9]\)/\1minty\2minty\3minty\4/g;
s/\([^a-zA-Z0-9]\)mint\([^a-zA-Z0-9]\)mint\([^a-zA-Z0-9]\)/\1minty\2minty\3/g;
s/\([^a-zA-Z0-9]\)mint\([^a-zA-Z0-9]\)/\1minty\2/g;
'
# minty 0mint minty mint0 minty__minty minty__ minty_ -minty minty minty minty_ minty -minty- minty minty mintmint minty
```