# sed whole word search and replace

Tags: shell, sed, hp-ux

How to replace whole words in string
[sed whole word search and replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032023/sed-whole-word-search-and-replace)

with sed in HP-UX (B.11.31)?

```
$ echo "bar embarassment" | sed "s/bar/no bar/g";

"\bbar\b" does not work
"\<bar\>" does not work
"[[:<:]]bar[[:>:]]" does not work
```

Comment: Install and use GNU `sed`?  Use `perl` instead?  Neither suggestion is wholly facetious.  Historically, building GCC on HP-UX required a non-standard version of `sed` (effectively, GNU `sed`) because the one provided by HP had constraint limits that the GCC configuration script could not reasonably live within.  I haven't built GCC on an HP-UX 11.x system (10.x was the last time), so I don't know if that is still a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `-r` option of `sed` with `\b`:

```
echo "bar embarassment" | sed -r "s/\bbar\b/no bar/g";
```

Answer (score 1):

Tested on solaris, not hpux

```
echo "bar embarassment bar foobar bar" | 
sed -e 's/\([^[:graph:]]\)bar$/\1no bar/g'  \
    -e 's/\([^[:graph:]]\)bar\([^[:graph:]]\)/\1no bar\2/g' \
    -e 's/^bar\([^[:graph:]]\)/no bar\1/g'
```

emits

```
no bar embarassment no bar foobar no bar
```

Comment: Would `[:alnum:]` be better than `[:graph:]` since graphical characters are those which are visible and hence include punctuation?

Comment: Maybe. Depends on the OP's definition of "whole word", particularly as underscore is a `[:punct:]` character.

Answer (score 0):

if you are in vim, you can use this command:

```
:% s/\<old\>/new/g
```