# Can Xcode find/replace in XIBs?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4

If I use Xcode's "Find/Replace in workspace" it seems to skip any text contained in the UIViews in XIB files.

Anyway to do this in Xcode or do I need to use another tool?

Thanks!

Comment: I ended up using a 3rd party find and replace tool to change text across a number of XIBs.  Careful though, things like an "&" will need be replaced with &amp; or you will get errors when you try and reopen the XIB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find and replace option of Xcode if for text/string replacement not for files.

If you want to do this you can have your shell script/ apple script.

Answer (score 2):

XCode will successfully Refactor IBOutlet names even if they are connected up in the nib. So to answer you:

Before choosing Find/Replace on the text, first see if Xcode will Refactor it instead. It won't refactor certain things (such as enums and #defines). If it will Refactor your target text then choose that and it should be okay.

Comment: Not looking to refactor outlets here.  Specifically the text contained in UIViews

Answer (score 2):

You can use find and sed from the command line

```
find . -name '*.xib' -type f -exec sed -i "" 's/OldText/NewText/g' {} \
```

For instance, I just had to find and replace all class prefixed from SC to MCSC and I used:

```
find . -name '*.xib' -type f -exec sed -i "" 's/[[:<:]]SC/MCSC/g' {} \
```

The [[:<:]] indicates a word boundary on OS X (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5734237/456366).

Comment: worked like a charm! Just note that there is ';' at the end(I don't know if it's a typo or SO ignores it).

Answer (score 1):

If you really have a lot of this text you want to find/replace, you might find **IBTool** usefull.

It's usually used to export/import texts from/into .XIB for translation reasons, but it should fit your needs, too.

You can see example of IBTool usage on [iPhone Applications Localization Guide](http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/iphone-applications-localization-guide/). You'd be interested in points 2 and 5 of the guide.

- you export the strings using IBTool
- you do find/replace in any text editor
- you reimport the string