# Sed regexp looking for either whitespace or end of line

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to detect a pattern that has three parts:

1. A space
2. Either an "m" or a "t"
3. Either a space or the end of a line

I want to keep #2 and #3. For example, I'd like to change *"i m sure he doesn t"* to *"im sure he doesnt"*

I'm having trouble expressing #3, since `[ $]` only seems to match spaces, not line-ends. Here's what I've tried:

```
$ echo "i m sure he doesn t" | sed 's/ \([mt]\)\([ $]\)/\1\2/g'
im sure he doesn t
```

How should I express "either a space or end of line" in the expression above? Thanks!

Comment: Once you put `$` inside `[]`, it is treated literally and not as an end-of-line marker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just matching space, then m or t, then space or newline won't catch cases with punctuation, e.g. a missing `'` in `"please don t!"`. A more general solution is to use word boundaries instead:

```
echo "i m sure he doesn t test test don t." | sed 's/ \([mt]\)[[:>:]]/\1/g'
```

The funky `[[:>:]]` is required on OS X (which I use), see Larry Gerndt's answer to [sed whole word search and replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032023/sed-whole-word-search-and-replace). On other sed flavors you may be able to use `\b` (any word boundary) or `\>` instead.

```
# example with word boundary
echo "i m sure he doesn t test test don t." | sed 's/ \([mt]\)[[:>:]]/\1/g'
im sure he doesnt test test dont.
```

Comment: Perfect! I'm not on a mac, so this is what worked for me: `sed 's/ \([mt]\)\>/\1/g'`

Answer (score 5):

Space or end of line? Use `|`:

```
s/ \([mt]\)\( \|$\)/\1\2/g
```

Comment: This one doesn't work for me. It still ignores the end of line. `$ echo "i m sure he doesn t" | sed 's/ \([mt]\)\( \|$\)/\1\2/' 
im sure he doesn t
`

Comment: Are there different flavors of unix or sed that would be giving me different results? If so, how do I figure out which one I'm using?

Comment: @Moira: Just add the `/g` at the end.

Comment: It took me quite a while to discover that this didn't work for me, because I was using the pipe (`|`) as a separator, which doesn't seem to mix well with the logical OR (`\|`).  Using `/` (or `:`) as a separator fixes that.

Comment: @AstroFloyd: You can always use `|` and `\|` to mean the different things, but it makes the expression even less readable than usual.

Comment: @choroba Your `echo "i m sure he doesn t" | sed 's/ \([mt]\)\( \|$\)/\1\2/g'` works for me (using GNU sed), but as soon as I replace your `/` with `|` it stops working...

Comment: @AstroFloyd You need to switch to extended regexes for it to work: `sed -E 's| ([mt])( \|$)|\1\2|g'`

Comment: @choroba Indeed (and remove the slashes from `\(...\)`.  The fact remains that each of `|` as a delimiter and `\|` as logical OR work without `-E` alone, but not together.  I thought it might be useful comment for others using `|` to read this instead of figuring it out.  No criticism of your answer, just a comment :-)

Answer (score 0):

Make last space optional:

```
sed 's/[ ]\([mt][ ]\?\)$/\1/' input
```

Posix friendly version:

```
sed 's/[ ]\([mt][ ]\{,1\}\)$/\1/' input
```