# How to remove this string in file

Tags: unix, sed

I want to remove a string in a file, the string I want to remove is 
"`/package/myname:`". I try to use `sed` to do that but could not. 
Note there are a '`/`' at beginning and '`:`' at the end of the string which I do not know how to handle.

e.g. I was able to remove "`package/myname`" using:

```
echo 'diff a/package/myname:/src/com/abc' | sed -e 's/\<package\/myname\>//g'
```

But when I run:

```
echo 'diff a/package/myname:/src/com/abc' | sed -e 's/\<\/package\/myname\:\>//g'
```

the result does not replace anything.

What is the right way to remove "/package/myname:" in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem:**

```
echo 'diff a/package/myname:/src/com/abc' | sed -e 's/\<\/package\/myname\:\>//g'
                                                       ^                    ^
                                                       |                    |
```

problem is mainly because of the two word boundaries.

`\<` - Boundary which matches between a non-word character and a word character.

`\>` - Boundary which matches between a word character and a word character and a non-word character.

So in the first case,

```
echo 'diff a/package/myname:/src/com/abc' | sed -e 's/\<package\/myname\>//g'
```

The `\<` before the `package` string matches the boundary which exists after `/` (non-word character) and `p` (word character). Likewise `\>` matches the boundary which exists between `e` (word character) and `:` (non-word character). So finally a match would occur and the characters which are matched are replaced by the empty string.

But in the second case,

```
echo 'diff a/package/myname:/src/com/abc' | sed -e 's/\<\/package\/myname\:\>//g'
```

`\<` fails to match the boundary which exists between `a` and forward slash `/` because `\<` matches only between the non-word character (*left*) and a word character (*right*) . Likewise `\>` fails to match the boundary which exists between `:` and `/` forward slash because there isn't a word character in the left and non-word character at the right.

**Solution:**

So, i suggest you to remove the word boundaries `<\` and `/>`. Or, you could do like this,

```
$ echo 'diff a/package/myname:/src/com/abc' | sed -e 's/\>\/package\/myname\://g'
diff a/src/com/abc
```

I think now you could figure out the reason for the working of above command.

Comment: @Abinash: perfect answer! In fact I was not clear about the word boundary /< when I asked this question. Now I realized that it is used only if I need to remove a string which is a WHOLE word in stead of partial word. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032023/sed-whole-word-search-and-replace. So in my case, I should not include the word boudary in sed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's%/package/myname:%%g'
```

using `%` instead of `/` to mark the ends of the sections of the substitute command. You can use any character that doesn't appear in the string.  It can be quite effective to use <kbd>Control-A</kbd> as the delimiter, even.

You could also use:

```
sed 's/\/package\/myname://g'
```

but I prefer to avoid messing around with backslashes when there's an easy way to avoid them.

Answer (score 1):

```
 sed -i "s/\/package\/myname\://g;" [__YOUR_FILE_NAME__]
```

That removes the phrase.

Doesn't not remove the line.

```
grep -v  # removes the line
```

Comment: `sed` is perfectly capable of deleting the line, of course: `sed '/\/package\/myname:/d'` does the job nicely.  I'm not sure about the `\:` in your notation — did you test it?  And the semicolon is superfluous but benign.

Comment: Yeah - I tested.  sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2.  Doesn't remove the line, just the test I tell it to remove. you can choose to \: or not - just trying to be helpful

Comment: @Jonathan and terary: Thanks for your answer. After comparing your command with mine, I realized that I should not have included word boundary in my command, the word boundary is used only to remove a whole word, not a partical word in a string.