# Linux - How to replace a string without removing it in other patterns that contains it

Tags: linux, terminal

I want to replace a string 'abc' with 'xyz', but there are other strings also contains 'abc', for example, 'abcdef'. I want to only replace exact match of 'abc', not 'abc' in 'abcef'. How would I accomplish that in linux?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this solution suffice - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032023/sed-whole-word-search-and-replace?

Comment: @zedfoxus Thanks! This is what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use "exact matches". For example, using a simple search and replace via `sed` generates behaviour you don't want:

**Code Listing (Faulty Case)**

```
echo "abc abcd abcdef" | sed 's/abc/xyz/g'
```

**Example (Faulty Case)**

```
xyz xyzd xyzdef
```

---

However, if you wrap your search query with `<` `>` chevrons (they need to be escaped with a backslash), you're good to go:

**Code (Working Case)**

```
echo "abc abcd abcdef" | sed 's/\<abc\>/xyz/g'
```

**Example (Working Case)**

```
xyz abcd abcdef
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish what you want using the line end limiting character `$`. Example:

```
$ echo abcdef | sed -e 's/abc$/.../'
abcdef

$ echo abc | sed -e 's/abc$/.../'
...
```

Which will only match `abc` without any following characters. (it will however match `123abc`). To further limit the match to only the string `abc` alone use the above in combination with the beginning of line character `^`:

```
$ echo abcdef | sed -e 's/^abc$/.../'
abcdef

$ echo abc | sed -e 's/^abc$/.../'
...

$ echo 123abc | sed -e 's/^abc$/.../'
123abc
```

Using both the line begin and line end limiting characters, you can limit substitution to only `abc`.

If your shell is `bash` and you would like to use the builtin `=~` operator to test against the regular expression in a script, without relying on external tools like `sed`, then you can accomplish the same thing in the following way:

```
#!/bin/bash

s1=${1:-abcdef}
pat=${2:-abc}
rep=${3:-...}

printf "\n string: %s  pattern: %s  replacement: %s\n" $s1 $pat $rep

[[ $s1 =~ ^${pat}$ ]] && s1=${s1/$pat/$rep}

printf "\n final string: %s\n\n" $s1

exit 0
```

**Output**

```
$ bash strpatrep.sh

 string: abcdef  pattern: abc  replacement: ...

 final string: abcdef

$ bash strpatrep.sh abc

 string: abc  pattern: abc  replacement: ...

 final string: ...

$ bash strpatrep.sh 123abc

 string: 123abc  pattern: abc  replacement: ...

 final string: 123abc
```