# Sed exact match search and replace on HP-UX

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, sed

As per [sed whole word search and replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032023/sed-whole-word-search-and-replace) I have tried the following.

OS: `HP-UX B.11.31 U ia64`

```
$ echo "bar bar2 embarassment" | sed "s/\<bar\>/test/g"
bar bar2 embarassment

$ echo "bar bar2 embarassment" | sed "s/\b[bar]\b/test/g"
bar bar2 embarassment

$ echo "bar bar2 embarassment" | sed "s/\[[:<:]]bar[[:<:]]\/test/g"
sed: Function s/\[[:<:]]bar[[:<:]]\/test/g cannot be parsed.

$ echo "bar bar2 embarassment" | sed "s/bar/test/g"
test test2 embraassment
```

None of the above are helping me to match the exact values.

Note: I can't install GNU `sed` since I don't have permission to do so.

Comment: This one `sed -E 's/([ ]|^)bar([ ]|$)/\1test\2/g'`

Comment: @perreal yes... that does work.. please put it answer :) thanks

Comment: @perreal oops.. wait it gives me an error... `Illegal Option -- E`

Comment: does it work if you remove `E`?

Comment: @perreal I get this `sed: Function s/([ ]|^)bar([ ]|$)/\1test\2/g cannot be parsed.` when i remove E

Comment: do you have `gsed` on that system?

Comment: What version of sed do you have ?

Comment: The version of `sed` on HP-UX is rather limited; when GCC is installed, the configuration process detects and rejects the HP-UX `sed` as inadequate.  When you say "you can't install GNU `sed`", does that mean you have no C compiler (and build system) on the machine, or just that you can't install it in the system directories?  If you have the compiler and `make`, you can configure `sed` to be installed under `$HOME/gnu` (the binary would be `$HOME/gnu/bin/sed`) with `--prefix=$HOME/gnu`, and you're surely allowed to create files under your home directory.

Comment: @ChamaraKeragala, your third attempt should work if you remove the backslashes.  `[[:<:]]` is a character class, and no part of it should be "escaped".  `echo "bar bar2 embarassment" | sed 's/[[:<:]]bar[[:<:]]/test/g'
` works for me in an ancient sed (albeit not HP/UX).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most portable method :)

```
sed 's/^bar$/test/;s/ bar / test /g;s/^bar /test /;s/ bar$/ test/'
```

You can also allow all non-alphanum characters:

```
sed 's/([^a-zA-Z0-9])bar([^a-zA-Z0-9])/\1test\2/g;s/^bar([^a-zA-Z0-9])/test\1/'
```

Comment: ok.. yes but this doesn;t work for something like.. `echo "bar,bar2` :]

Comment: can you pls provide an example?

Comment: added a second example, basically you can do this for all whitespace characters of the first examlpe