# \< and \> in sed

Tags: regex, bash, macos, sed

I'm reading [this regex tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Regular.html#uh-9) and it says:

> The pattern to search for the word "the" would be "\<[tT]he>".

How come this doesn't output `bar bar`?

```
○ → echo "foo bar" | sed -E 's/\<foo\>/bar/'
foo bar
```

Can `\<` and `\>` be used in sed?

Comment: [It does here](https://ideone.com/n1YDfD).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew weird.  I'm using OSX

Comment: Then maybe BSD sed doesn't work this way and the tutorial is for GNU sed.

Comment: Ah, that explains it. `sed` implementations differ. Try `sed 's/[[:<:]]foo[[:>:]]/bar/'`

Comment: This would be pretty convenient.  Does the OSX version have an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

`\<` and `\>` are used for word boundaries but it is platform dependent.

On OSX `sed` you need to use `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` for the same:

```
echo "foo food bar" | sed -E 's/[[:<:]]foo[[:>:]]/bar/'

bar food bar
```

However if you can install `gnu sed` on OSX using `brew` package installer then you can use:

```
echo "foo food bar" | gsed -E 's/\bfoo\b/bar/'

bar food bar
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5734237/3832970

Comment: Documentation for `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` can be found in `man re_format`, which documents the style of regular expressions accepted by `sed`.