# BASH replace a single letter only when it's alone not in a word

Tags: bash

I do not want to replace just any letters with words. I only want to replace letters that are stand alone with exact case sensitive matches.

I have a file that looks like this:

```
file>-string pile stage one on one/a>b
system > use while one is one stage/sump/f
get sole--> one by one dir/sub/main/c >b
multi string return one by one sub//c static a
ect...
ect...
```

I want to replace the letter that are not part of word.

```
a=ASTRING
b=BSTRING
c=CSTRING
f=FSTRING
```

The desired output would look like:

```
file>-string pile stage one on one/ASTRING>BSTRING
system > use while one is one stage/sump/FSTRING
get sole--> one by one dir/sub/main/CSTRING >BSTRING
multi string return one by one sub//CSTRING static ASTRING
ect...
ect...
```

Here is what I have been trying:

```
sed -i "s|a|ASTRING|g" file.txt

grep [a] file.txt | sed -i "s|a|ASTRING|g"

Repeated for b c f
```

Comment: That's not a bash question, that's an `sed` question, isn't it? There's a special symbol \b meaning "word boundary" in the regex.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sed whole word search and replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032023/sed-whole-word-search-and-replace)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\b` in the regular expression to match a word boundary.

```
sed -i 's/\ba\b/ASTRING/g' file.txt
```

BTW, you can't use `-i` if you're piping the input to `sed`, the filename has to be an argument to `sed`. If it gets its input from standard input, it doesn't know the filename so it can't update the file in place.

Answer (score 0):

nameref variables to the rescue.

```
a=ASTRING
b=BSTRING
c=CSTRING
f=FSTRING
for v in a b c f
do declare -n R=$v
   sed -Ei "s/\\b$v\\b/$R/g" file.txt
done
```

Comment: Why not just use an associative array?

Comment: Considered it, but this was abstract enough that I wanted to keep the example simpler.