# Replace the whole word with AWK

Tags: bash, awk

In the following example:

```sh
echo "manoeuvre man track" | awk -v replace="man" '{ gsub(replace, ""); print }'
```

I get this result:

```
oeuvre  track
```

I would like it to replace text only when it finds the whole word, so as a result, I would get:

```
manoeuvre  track
```

(only the word man was removed)

--

- I tried this with word boundaries (\b and \y), but I cannot understand how to apply them here.
- I made it work with a for loop, but I thought maybe there is a more straightforward way using gsub?
- I only have AWK and don't have gAWK.

```
# awk --version
awk version 20200816
```

Comment: Can you use sed?
if you can use sed take a look to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032023/sed-whole-word-search-and-replace)

Comment: What is your definition of _word_? Letters separated by blanks? Is there any punctuation?

Comment: @anubhava I voted to reopen. This is more about _replacing_ than it is _matching_.

Comment: ok that's fair point @glennjackman

Comment: You can not use `\y` if you do not have gAWK, as it is one of [`gawk`-Specific Regexp Operators](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/GNU-Regexp-Operators.html)

Comment: Also what do you mean by "only have AWK"? Can you scry version using `awk --version` and add it to your question?

Answer (score 4):

This may be what you're trying to do, using any awk, assuming you want the first full-field literal string match:

```
$ echo "manoeuvre man track" |
    awk -v replace="man" '
        s=index(" "$0" "," "replace" ") {
            $0 = substr($0,1,s-2) substr($0,s+length(replace))
        }
        { print }
    '
manoeuvre track
```

or this if you want to do a full-field regexp match for all fields:

```
$ echo "manoeuvre man track" |
    awk -v replace="man" '
        {
            $0=" "$0" "
            gsub(" "replace" "," ")
            gsub(/^ | $/,"",$0)
            print
        }
    '
manoeuvre track
```

There are lots of other possibilities...

Comment: @anubhava I said "assuming you want the first..."

Comment: and it does so. It replaces the whole first word while not replacing parts of words as the OP demonstrated was a problem.

Comment: May be I misunderstood but I thought OP wants to replace all the whole words in a line

Comment: OK, I added another version that may also be what the OP wants It's hard to tell from the question.

Comment: ++ to this answer but unfortunately it will miss 2nd `man` in `manoeuvre man man track man`

Answer (score 2):

Building on to the [Ed's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71666379/548225) to address multiple search word appearing next to each other:

```sh
cat file
manoeuvre man man man mantrack man

awk -v replace="man" '
{
   $0 = " " $0 " "                # pad space on each side of the line
   gsub("( " replace ")+ ", " ")  # replace 1+ repetitions of man with a space
   gsub(/^ | $/, "")              # remove space from both sides of the line
}
1' file

manoeuvre mantrack
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a good trick there with adding extra spaces in the beginning so that the pattern in gsub would match.

Answer (score 1):

"Vanilla" awk is not a good fit for this task. I'd use perl:

```sh
$ echo "manoeuvre man track" |perl -pe 's/\bman\b//g'
manoeuvre  track
```

or if you want to pass "man" as a parameter:

```sh
$ echo "manoeuvre man track" |perl -spe 's/\b${word}\b//g' -- -word=man
manoeuvre  track
```

---

One last point: if you want the "word" treated as a literal string, use the `\Q...\E` regex markers:

```sh
$ echo "manoeuvre man m.n trackm.n" |perl -spe 's/\b${word}\b//g' -- -word=m.n
manoeuvre   trackm.n

$ echo "manoeuvre man m.n trackm.n" |perl -spe 's/\b\Q${word}\E\b//g' -- -word=m.n
manoeuvre man  trackm.n
```

Comment: Just FYI, word boundaries do not help much if the *word* can contain special chars (like e.g. `.`) at the start and end.

Answer (score 1):

Since you cannot use a GNU `awk`, you CAN'T use word boundaries. You would need a tool that does. For example, Perl.

If you can use Perl, you can use a solution like [Glenn's one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71665544/3832970), but I'd use a but modified approach:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
text="manoeuvre man man trackman"
replace="man"
perl -spe 's/\s*(?!\B\w)\Q${replace}\E(?<!\w\B)//g' -- -replace="$replace" <<< "$text"
## => manoeuvre trackman
```

See [this online demo](http://apps-loc:8080/sandbox.aspx).

**Details**:

- `s` - allows using custom switches
- `p` - reads the file line by line
- `e` - signals the end of options, and the next thing will be the command
- `\s*(?!\B\w)\Q${replace}\E(?<!\w\B)` - a regex that matches

  - `\s*` - one or more whitespaces
  - `(?!\B\w)` - a left-hand adaptive dynamic word boundary
  - `\Q${replace}\E` - a `replace` "word" (that can be any string with any special and non-special chars) where `\Q` and `\E` quote (escape) all special regex meta chars automatically (as they are treated as literal chars)
  - `(?<!\w\B)` - a right-hand adaptive dynamic word boundary.

Note that adaptive word boundaries will work best in cases when you do not know if the "word" one passes to the regex pattern starts or ends with special (i.e. "non-word") characters.

**If you had a GNU `awk`**, you could use something like:

```sh
awk -v replace="man" '{gsub("\\<"replace"\\>", "")}1'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/5BaqXI):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s="manoeuvre man track"
awk -v replace="man" '{gsub("\\<"replace"\\>", "")}1' <<< "$s"
# => manoeuvre  track
```

**NOTE**:

- Word boundaries here are `\<` and `\>`, and to use a literal `\` char in the `awk` command, it needs doubling
- `replace` is a variable containing just word chars, so it is OK to use `\<` and `\>` word boundaries to wrap this value to match as a whole word (it would be more complicated if it contained non-word chars)
- To create a pattern from a variable, you need to concatenate the values, here, it is done with `"\\<"replace"\\>"`.
- Note that `print` is replaced with `1` in the code above.

Comment: @Thefourthbird I added a Perl solution.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification on word boundaries. However, a Perl solution is not what I'm looking for. Though, it might be a good one :)

Comment: @MishaSlyusarev My Perl solution is the only precise one in the scenario when you do not know what chars your search string consists of. See my YT video about [dynamic adaptive word boundaries](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ngbxagE2b68.)

Answer (score 0):

Worst case, manually hack the likely occurrences -
*(edit - Thanks, anubhava)*

```
$: echo "man man man man man - manual man is really manners man" | 
    awk -v replace="man" '{
      while ($0~"[[:space:]]"replace"[[:space:]]") {
       gsub("[[:space:]]+"replace"[[:space:]]+"," ");
      }
      gsub("^"replace"[[:space:]]+","");
      gsub("[[:space:]]+"replace"$","");
   } 1'
- manual is really manners
```

As anubhava pointed out in the comments, the space-on-either-side check can be tricked by multiple consecutive occurrences of the pattern, so the scan needs to make multiple passes to be sure.
If you care to try `sed` it can do boundary markers and doesn't have that problem -

```
$:  echo "man man man man man - manual man is really manners man" | sed -E 's/\<man\>/ /g; s/  +/ /g;'
 - manual is really manners
```

Note that multiples at the front still leaves a leading space -you can always add one more check and clean to the pattern list.

If you have GNU `awk`, and maybe don't care about the double spaces -

```
$: echo "manual man has manners" | awk '{gsub("\\<man\\>","")}1'
manual  has manners
```

Be sure to double-slash the metachars. If you really want to supply the pattern as a variable on the command line, especially with GNU `awk` using border markers, watch out for double-parsing. You will still need double-backslash quoting if you use single-ticks, or *four* if you double-quote...

```
$: echo "manual man has manners" | awk -v replace='\\<man\\>' '{gsub(replace,"")}1'
manual has manners
$: echo "manual man has manners" | awk -v replace="\\\\<man\\\\>" '{gsub(replace,"")}1'
manual has manners
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestions! I think "\\<" only works in gawk and doesn't work in awk.

Comment: You can also just provide all possible pattern cases. Edited with example.

Comment: It will fail for the case of `manoeuvre man man man mantrack ma`

Comment: Great catch, thanks - edited.