# How to replace "00" in data with "N/A" skipping first row in sed?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I'm working with GWAS data, My data looks like this:

```
IID,kgp11004425,rs11274005,kgp183005,rs746410036,kgp7979600
1,00,AG,GT,AK,00
32,AG,GG,AA,00,AT
300,TT,AA,00,AG,AA       
400,GG,AG,00,GT,GG
```

Desired Output:

```
IID,kgp11004425,rs11274005,kgp183005,rs746410036,kgp7979600
1,N/A,AG,GT,AK,N/A
32,AG,GG,AA,N/A,AT
98,TT,AA,N/A,AG,AA       
3,GG,AG,N/A,GT,GG
```

Here I'm trying to replace "00" with "N/A", but since I have 00 in the first_row/header_row and First column i.e IId, it's replacing here with N/A like kgp11N/A4425, rs11274N/A5,kgp183N/A5....
and Id column values with 300, 400, 500 as 3N/A, 4N/A, 5N/A. The bash command I used:

```
sed 's~00~N/A~g' allSNIPsFinaldata.csv
```

Can anyone please help "how not to include/Skip the first row or header row and first column and apply this effect. please help

Comment: What's your field separator? Multiple spaces or one tab?

Comment: Add output of `file allSNIPsFinaldata.csv` to your question (no comment).

Comment: My field separator is Multiple Spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may specify an address to select the line(s) to apply the command to. Thus you might choose to exclude the first line like this:

```
sed '1!s~00~N/A~g' allSNIPsFinaldata.csv
```

As a sidenote I'd like to note that your example isn't actually CSV despite the file name; your header is comma-delimited but the rest of the file is using spaces.

Comment: Just a note that it will replace `100` with `1N/A`

Comment: @anubhava, the above command, replaced 100, 200, 300, 400  values as 2NA, 3NA.. in the IID column which is the problem here, how can I skip First Row and First Column as well and perform the above operation

Comment: @Klaus Klein, the above command, replaced 100, 200, 300, 400 as 1NA, 2NA,... in the IID column which is the problem here, how can I skip First Row and First Column as well and perform the above operation

Comment: @RajuNatha: [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71949532/548225) already takes care of that but you overlooked that.

Answer (score 2):

With 2 capture groups you can use this `sed`:

```sh
sed -E 's~(^|[[:blank:]])00([[:blank:]]|$)~\1N/A\2~g' file

IID, kgp11004425, rs11274005, kgp183005, rs746410036, kgp7979600
1       N/A           AG        GT            AK          N/A
32      AG           GG        AA            N/A          AT
98      TT           AA        N/A            AG          AA
3       GG           AG        N/A            GT          GG
```

**Details:**

- `(^|[[:blank:]])`: Match start or a whitespace in capture group #1
- `00`: Match `00`
- `([[:blank:]]|$)`: Match end or a whitespace in capture group #2
- `\1N/A\2`: Replacement to put back value of capture group #1 followed by `N/A` followed by value of capture group #2

Comment: I have just given sample data, like the above data I have 522 rows and 2583 columns. Will, it still be able to work?

Comment: If you note global flag it will replace all of those values

Answer (score 0):

You might also skip the first row starting from the second one:

```
sed '2,$s~00~N/A~g' allSNIPsFinaldata.csv
```

If you don't want partial word matches, you can implement word boundaries around the `00` [in different ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032023/sed-whole-word-search-and-replace).